# Missing Carriage Return in Docker for Mac Containers

Tags: bash, macos, docker

All of a sudden all of my `docker/docker-compose exec/run` commands are printing logs that are lacking a carriage return making command line impossible to read due to indentation (see photos below).

I re-installed docker to factory settings, but that didn't fix anything.

where else should I look to solve this sort of problem?

**Update** 
This is an active issue in [docker-for-mac](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1681).

I just updated to 17.06.0-rc1-ce-mac13 and that is when I started having the problems.

Also, can you leave a comment if you are voting to close?

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is nothing wrong with the logs; it's your *terminal settings*.

Comment: That make sense Charles Duffy. I'm looking into that.

Comment: The `reset` command, in getting your TTY back to a known-good condition, will clear this state (but also clear your screen, so it may not be what you want). You could also use `stty sane`, without the screen-clearing side effect.

Comment: Consider dumping the output of `stty -a` both when your terminal is in a good state and when it's misbehaving.

Comment: Actually, I think I've found a proper duplicate of this over on SuperUser: https://superuser.com/a/199107

Comment: I tried `reset` in bash to no avail. A key part of this is that it only happens when I enter a shell within a Docker container.

Comment: Tried it where, exactly? In a *local* bash shell after getting out of Docker, and the issue still wasn't fixed? (That would surprise me). In a remote shell? (That wouldn't surprise me a bit; means the TTY configuration isn't getting passed through properly, which... yup, totally believable).

Comment: Incidentally, the dumb-workaround thing is just to filter your logs through a pipeline that changes `\n` to `\r\n` on their way to your terminal. (Having only a `\n` is the canonically correct thing for storage *on disk* on UNIX-family operating systems, so you'd want that filter to operate at the display layer only).

Comment: Yes I ran it in a *local* bash shell *after* exiting Docker.

Comment: And pressing enter in that shell still was doing the staircase thing? Definitely a surprise. Mind you, that it's happening at a shell is *definitive* proof that it's a TTY configuration thing vs a problem with the contents of the logs, but a diagnosis is definitely less helpful than a fix here...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145755/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-eric-h).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an application defect in the release candidate with an open issue.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, thought I was going crazy.  I only see the problem when using `docker-compose run` so I've been adding the `stty onlcr` which works a charm.

Comment: 17.06-rc2 is out and it looks like it included the fix for this issue. Try upgrading now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To work around this recent regression in Docker, execute:

```
stty onlcr
```

This adds an implicit carriage return after each newline.

```
CharlessMacBook:~ cduffy$ docker run -t -i bash
bash-4.4#
          bash-4.4#
                    bash-4.4# stty onlcr
                                        bash-4.4#
bash-4.4#
bash-4.4#
```

Comment: No dice. This is related specifically to docker interaction. This (https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8513) is a similar issue, but I've not changed the Docker commands I've run and this just started happening today.

Comment: Are you passing the `-t` argument to `docker run`? If not, then there's no TTY visible inside the container, so `stty` and `reset` and the like can't work there.

Comment: `docker-compose exec database mysql ...` Where database is a running container of https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue yesterday after upgrading to the newest docker edge for mac (same version as Eric's). Does anyone have a solution for this? It is really annoying.

**EDIT:** My temporary solution to run units:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml exec php bash -c "stty onlcr && php bin/phpunit"
```

You can use it if you want to run commands other than bash prompt.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above this is a defect in the Edge version of Docker for OSX:

> Version 17.06.0-rc1-ce-mac13 (18169) 
>   Channel: edge

If you unintentionally selected the edge channel, or no longer need its bleeding edge features simply switch back to the stable channel.

Go to Docker -> Preferences and at the bottom it should say "The is an edge version. You can switch to stable".

- Click `stable` then select OK in the dialog that pops up next.
- Download the stable .dmg file from https://download.docker.com/mac/stable/Docker.dmg
- Quit your running docker
- Open the dmg file
- Select if you want to replace the current edge docker or replace it
- Open Docker with Finder - it will tell you it is going to uninstall the beta version and restart the app with a warning that you will lose your containers and settings.
- Press Continue and Restart and complete the installation

Welcome back from the edge!

You are now back to the stable channel and stable version of Docker.

Be prepared to rebuild all your containers before you can use them again.

Share and enjoy!