# Docker Container Shell Tab Hell

Tags: django, shell, docker

Richard Hendricks has infected my Docker container and is adding tabs to every new line of output even after just hitting enter repeatedly , example below. Please help stop this madness!

```
(devops)Daves-MacBook-Pro:database-manager dave$ docker exec -it devops-api sh
/var/devops #
              /var/devops #
                            /var/devops #
                                          /var/devops #
                                                        /var/devops #
                                                                      /var/devops #
                                                                                    /var/devops #
                                                                                                  /var/devops #
                                                                                                                /var/devops #
                                                                                                                              /var/devops # exit
                                                                                                                                                (devops)Daves-MacBook-Pro:database-manager dave$
```

EDIT:
The image in my Dockfile is `python:3.6-alpine` and building the image using `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: Can you post what image you are using behind, the content of how you build it?

Comment: @German, added an edit to the description

Comment: Did you test it with the base image?, To dismiss the problems within the construction of your image.

Comment: @German: Yes this is with a base image with nothing contributing to the image. Tested this on multiple images; `alpine`, `python:3.6`, `python:3.6-alpine`

Comment: I mean it may be is in the your Dockerfile the problem, you can post your definition.

Comment: @BMitch You are correct, this is a duplicate of that issue. It seems to be a bug in Docker for Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicate of another issue but it also seems to be a bug in Docker for Mac

[Missing Carriage Return in Docker for Mac Containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44339237/missing-carriage-return-in-docker-for-mac-containers)